# Python Selenium button isn't being clicked

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to scrape data from this website (https://www.ilcollege2career.com/#/) using python (selenium and beautiful soup).

The code I have is this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('my file path')

driver.get('https://www.ilcollege2career.com/#/')

first_click = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tutorial-modal"]/div/div/div/div[3]/button[1]')))
first_click.click()

second_click = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tutorial-start-modal"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]')))
second_click.click()
```

So my problem is that while the first click works and it goes to the tutorial step the second click which will close the tutorial doesn't click. For some reason time.sleep() works but I don't want to have to keep repeating that every step. Am I doing something wrong?

I have also tried find element by css as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The xpath to the second_click is not accurate in the sense that it does not send the click to correct element. try this out,

```
driver.fullscreen_window()

driver.get('https://www.ilcollege2career.com/#/')

first_click = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tutorial-modal"]/div/div/div/div[3]/button[1]')))
first_click.click()
```

**Option#1** -

```
second_click = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@onclick='closeTutorial()']")))
second_click.click()
```

**Option#2 -**

```
second_click = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@onclick='closeTutorial()']")))
second_click.click()
```

Comment: I tried that XPATH and I end up getting an element click intercepted exception:                   Element <button type="button" class="btn close-btn" data-localize="tutorial.close" onclick="closeTutorial()">...</button> is not clickable at point (600, 667). Other element would receive the click: <div class="modal-footer welcome-btns">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.70)

Comment: try to get the window into full screen.see updated answer

Comment: I didn't get the exception this time and it ran, but I still come across the same issue as initially where it doesn't close out of the tutorial.

Comment: I was able to fix it. Thank you so much for your input. The problem that was happening was there was still something running in the background so it would never click out so I fixed that by doing WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'tutorial-modal'))) and then and if statement after that and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to those who are looking for it.

```
invisible = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'tutorial-modal')))

if invisible:
```

There was something running behind that wouldn't close out so I was never able to close that and by doing this I was able to exit out.